# Replacement of sudo in window without using third party tool

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, powershell, bash-scripting

Is there thing in windows to run a command as an administrator from command line.

I have a script and inside that I want to run following command as an administrator.

```
C:\User\Admin\assemblies\nssm.exe" install my_service D:\files\bin\logstash.bat" -f "D:\files\bin\myfile.conf > NUL
```

**NOTE:**

1. I do not want to use third party tool.
2. Command should be compatible with any windows OS version. e.g window 7, 8, 10 etc
3. I know I can right click my .bat file to run it as admin but I don't want that.

**What I have done so far:**

I am using this command **runas /user: Admin @ DESKTOPAKBHY**

But its not working I am getting following error:

**Can't openservice! OpenService(): The specified service does not exist as an installed service.**

Stuck need help. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525056/how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-run-cmd-as-administrator

Comment: Possible duplicate (link mentioned by @spikey_richie).